# How to calculate duration field when knowing start date field in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a document which contains these fields:

```
{
"start_date":"2021-04-23T07:27:50.296+0200",
"duration":"null",
}
```

and I have a few hundrends of entries. I was wondering if I there would be a way on elastic search to calculate the duration field in milliseconds, which will be calculating the time between the `start_date` and the moment the query is sent. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you explain the use-case? Why indexing a field with value null whose value is dynamic and based on current date time? How do you want to use the calculated value of `duration`?

Comment: hey @Nishant thank you so much for you response! some other documents of the index dont have a null value! what I want to do is calculate the duration for the entries which dont have it and then sort by duration!

Comment: Was this a miss, or it can happen that any new doc still can have the null value for this field? If it was a miss then you can re-index the docs with correct value which currently have null value for `duration` field.

Comment: no no it can happen @Nishant

Comment: Use [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_script_based_sorting).